# Tarski's truth theorem — semantic or syntactic?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

I was reading the sketch of the proof of Tarski's theorem in Jech's "Set Theory", which appears as Theorem 12.7, thinking that it would be an interesting result to really understand.  As stated in the book, it is essentially a syntactic result (after fixing a Gödel numbering).  However, after reading other proofs of Tarski's result, and really delving into the sketched proof, I believe that there is a serious error in Jech's proof, and now I'm not sure the result holds at the syntactic level.

Here is the problem as I see it.  In the second sentence of the proof the formulas are enumerated as $$\varphi_0,\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\ldots.$$  Now, this is an enumeration outside ZFC, so the subscripts are metamathematical numbers.  But in the next formula, which reads, $$x\in \omega \land \neg T(\#(\varphi_x(x))),$$ the subscript $x$ on $\varphi$ is being treated as a formal natural number---an element of $\omega$.

If we have a model of set theory, where $\omega$ matches the metamathematical natural numbers, maybe we could make this formula work.  My question is whether or not we can somehow avoid making such a strong assumption.  If not, what's the easiest way to assert such a matching (say, without forcing an interpretation of all of ZFC, just of the natural number part)?

Comment: Let the enumeration be recursive. Implement it inside the theory.

Comment: @MonroeEskew In fact we just need the enumeration to be definable.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Your comment doesn't seem to address the two questions I asked.

Comment: Yes it does.  Don't take the enumeration to be "outside."  Let $M$ be your model of a sufficiently strong theory.  We are proving that there is no formula $T(x)$ such that $M \models T(x)$ iff $x$ is a natural number of the model which codes a real sentence $\sigma$ such that $M \models \sigma$.  The reason is that $M$ can implement the recursive numeration of all formulas, which it may interpret as extending beyond the real integers, but which agrees on the real ones, and by Godel's argument we can construct a real sentence $\sigma$ such that $M \models \neg T(\#\sigma)$ iff $\sigma$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew The fact that you start with "Let $M$ be a model..." suggests that somehow were are not communicating here.  Let me try again.  Jech lists two formulas that define his truth condition.  The first is $\forall x\, (T(x)\rightarrow x\in \omega)$.  This is a formula in the FOL in the signature $(\in)$.  Similarly, however you define a Godel numbering $\#$ of the sentences in this FOL (whether recursively, or not), for each sentence $\sigma$, the statement $\sigma\leftrightarrow T(\#\sigma)$ is also a formula in this language.  Thus, it is valid to ask whether or not...

Comment: ...a predicate $T$ can be defined, satisfying these conditions, without reference to any model.  That is my first question.  Your comment may address my second question, if the answer to my first question is "no".

Comment: This *is* a theorem about models.  It is about undefinability of "truth" which means satisfaction.  We are showing that for any given model $M$ of ZFC (although this holds in more generality) is no formula $\phi(v)$ in the language of set theory such that $M \models \phi(x)$ iff $x$ is a standard natural number coding a sentence that is true in $M$.  If you like, we can restrict our attention to one preferred model, say "V".  I don't know how to phrase this result as a purely syntactic / provability result-- it's about satisfaction.

Comment: @MonroeEskew "If you like, we can restrict our attention to one preferred model, say "V"" FWIW I think (per my answer) that this is what Jech's doing - working implicitly in NBG and proving "$Th(V)$ is not definable in $V$."

Comment: @MonroeEskew No, Jech doesn't define his truth predicate in terms of satisfaction.  That's what motivated my question in the first place.  He defines it via a (metacountable) schema of statements holding.  For all I know, it is perfectly possible for there there be a definable predicate, satisfying his list of conditions, compatible with the axioms of ZFC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Jech is using as his metatheory the *class* theory $\mathsf{NBG}$. In this context, "true" is a proxy for "true in the (class-sized) structure $V$."

Specifically, the (more) formal version of the natural-language Theorem $12.7$ is the following:

> $Th(V)$ is not definable in $V$.

The definition of $Th(V)$ is taking place on the class level: it's a set of natural numbers defined by quantifying over classes. The same is true for the property "definable in $V$." So even though it looks like Jech is using a weirdly un-referring notion of "truth," it is in fact just the usual notion of truth with respect to a specific structure - that structure being $V$, and that whole facet of the argument being (annoyingly, perhaps) kept implicit. Note that this makes the whole "correctness-about-$\omega$" issue moot: Theorem $12.7$ is about a structure which by definition has the right $\omega$.

---

An in-my-opinion more satisfying version of the result, which makes correctness-about-$\omega$ nontrivial, is the following:

> $T$ proves that for all $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, $Th(\mathcal{M})$ is not the standard part of a definable subset of $\mathcal{M}$.

Here $T$ is a very weak theory indeed: $\mathsf{ACA_0^+}$ suffices (really the only need for strength being the requirement that the theory of a structure is actually a thing that makes sense in the first place - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3499652/28111)). Note that this version of the result does not apply only to models which are correct about $\omega$.

---

EDIT: And as Monroe Eskew pointed out below, if we drop models entirely we can go even lower. We can prove over a *very* weak base theory (e.g. $I\Sigma_1$ is already overkill) the following:

> If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, then there is no formula $\varphi$ such that for all sentences $\psi$ $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $\varphi(\#\psi)\leftrightarrow\psi$.

Comment: But I don't care what ZFC proves about its internal formulas.  I want, from a metatheoretical point of view, to know what it takes to show that there is not definable truth predicate for ZFC.  My metatheory doesn't necessary assume ZFC, per se.

Comment: @PaceNielsen What is a truth predicate for ZFC? Truth predicates only make sense for structures.

Comment: The natural-language version of Tarski's theorem is "$Th(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot)$ is not definable in $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot)$." To even express that, our metatheory needs to be able to talk about $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot)$ as a structure appropriately.

Comment: Regarding truth predicates requiring structure---that's what my question was asking about!  Jech defines a truth condition *without* any reference to a structure.  (See his condition (12.17) on page 162.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen No, there is a reference to a structure there although it's implicit: the book (if I recall correctly) uses $\mathsf{NBG}$ as the metatheory throughout. So $\mathsf{NBG}$ is proving "The set of sentences true in the structure $V$ is not a definable element of $V$." The structure in question is $V$ itself, which is a directly-handleable object in $\mathsf{NBG}$.

Comment: We can "de-classify" this along the usual lines of course: if we want to use $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as our metatheoy, Theorem $12.7$ is then understood as a natural-language version of a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of "If $\mathcal{M}\models \mathsf{ZFC}$ then $Th(\mathcal{M})$ is not (the standard part of) a definable subset of $\mathcal{M}$."

Comment: Note that if we take the $\mathsf{NBG}$ approach - which I think is what Jech is implicitly doing - then we are (in the metatheory $\mathsf{NBG}$) proving a result about the actual universe of all sets ($V$), so the issue of "correct natural numbers" doesn't come up. The "de-classed" version of the result in my previous comment is applicable more broadly.

Comment: Noah, rather than making guesses, perhaps you should find a copy of the book and look at the relevant sections.  In case you don't have a copy, here are the conditions: (i) $\forall x\, (T(x)\rightarrow x\in \omega)$ and (ii) for every sentence $\sigma$, then $\sigma\leftrightarrow T(\#\sigma)$.  As you can see, there is no reference to modeling here.  These conditions are independent of the choice of model.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I'm looking at the book right now. The only thing I'm guessing at is the book's specific choice of metatheory, which I'd have to search for. But regardless of whether he uses $\mathsf{NBG}$ or $\mathsf{MK}$ or similar, the point is the same: there **is** a specific model he's (implicitly) talking about there, namely the true $V$, and the truth definition is with respect to that (proper class sized) structure. That is, for Jech "true" is a proxy for "true in $V$."

Comment: @PaceNielsen I've edited my answer to hopefully better address your question; let me know if I'm still not getting your point.

Comment: No, it is still not right.  His definition of $T$ (the purported truth predicate) is purely syntactical (up to choice of Godel numbering).  He doesn't say $M\models \sigma$ if and only if $M\models T(\#\sigma)$.  He says that for each sentence $\sigma$, the formula $\sigma\leftrightarrow T(\#\sigma)$ is valid (i.e., true in all worlds).

Comment: @PaceNielsen No, he doesn't: he says "if $\sigma$ is a sentence [then] $T(\ulcorner\sigma\urcorner)$ holds if and only if $\sigma$ holds." "Holds" here is implicitly with respect to $V$. Where are you getting the contrary?

Comment: The wording in my version of the book is exactly the following: "if $\sigma$ is a sentence, then $\sigma\leftrightarrow T(\#\sigma)$."  This is a schema of assertions. For each statement $\sigma$ (in the FOL language in the signature $(\in)$, in the theory given by the axioms of ZFC and the usual logical axioms), it is being asserted that $\sigma\leftrightarrow T(\#\sigma)$ holds.

Comment: @PaceNielsen No, it's a single assertion and it's referring to what's true in $V$. (What does "holds" mean otherwise? It can't possibly refer to holding across all models of ZFC, since that **is** definable.)

Comment: The formal version of that definition is: "$T$ is the Godel number of a truth predicate iff ... (ii) if $\sigma$ is a sentence, then $V\models\sigma$ iff $V\models T(\#\sigma)$." This indeed uses satisfaction with respect to a specific structure, namely $V$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen You can also take from this argument the syntactic result that there is no formula $\phi(v)$ such that for every sentence $\sigma$, ZFC proves $\phi(\#\sigma) \leftrightarrow \sigma$.  Because given $\phi(v)$, you can construct a particular $\sigma$ that is provably equivalent to $\neg\phi(\#\sigma)$.  This is just Goedel's fixed point lemma.

Comment: @MonroeEskew And that syntactic result - or more accurately, that result with the hypothesis that ZFC is consistent - is itself provable in a very weak theory (way below $I\Sigma_1$ certainly).

Comment: @MonroeEskew Are you asserting the following metamathematical statement?  For every formula with one free variable $\varphi(v)$ in the signature $(\in)$, and every Godel numbering $\#$ of sentences in that language, there exists a sentence $\sigma$ such that ZFC proves $\sigma\leftrightarrow \neg\varphi(\#\sigma)$.  If so, where is the easiest place to find a complete (easy) proof of this?

Comment: And to clarify, by a Godel numbering, I mean an injective map from the true formulas of that signature (not the internal formulas) to the elements of $\omega$ (inside the formal system).

Comment: @PaceNielsen Yes, that's just Godel's diagonal lemma (and it's provable in $I\Sigma_1$ for example).

Comment: @PaceNielsen- See for example the end of the  first chapter of Kunen’s book.

Comment: Great, I think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I've added the diagonal lemma to my answer.

Comment: Perfect!  I've accepted the answer

Comment: @NoahSchweber There is one additional point.  I believe Godel's lemma requires that the numbering is given by a nice enough function.  What happens if you allow an arbitrary numbering?

Comment: @PaceNielsen Well, for an arbitrary numbering there's not much that can be said. For example, map all the true sentences onto the evens and the false sentences onto the odds. So some constraint is needed to get anything useful. The key properties we need for these sorts of results are **representability**, or **invariant definability**, properties: for example, we want there to be a formula $\psi$ such that for every standard $i,j,k$ we have $T\vdash\psi(i,j,k)$ iff $i=\#(\#^{-1}(j)\wedge\#^{-1}(k))$ and $T\vdash\neg\psi(i,j,k)$ otherwise. (cont'd)

Comment: So intuitively "conjunction is the standard part of a definable relation in all models of $T$." This is all nuked by the theorem that (for $T$ appropriate) the (total) computable functions are exactly the functions which are representable in $T$ in this sense; although it's overkill for that specific purpose, this result is generally proved in modern expositions of Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Noah, I don't think Jech is working in NBG (at least, he does not hint this at any point.) @PaceNielsen I think the issue here depends on whether you see this theorem as a single theorem or a *theorem scheme*. If you treat this as a theorem scheme for each $T(x)$, then he explicitly produces a sentence $\sigma$, for which we can prove that $\sigma \leftrightarrow \neg T(\# \sigma)$. If you want to see this a single theorem that quantifies over all formulas $T(x)$, then you need a satisfaction relation for proper classes which would require you to work in a class theory such as NBG.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: If you are bugged by this issue, it is also present in the definition of "truth definition". Is this a definition in ZFC, in which case all formulas in that definition are indeed the formal objects (sets) that represent those formulas, or is this a "metadefinition" that says that a formula $T(x)$ that I write down is a truth definition if I can prove the item (i) and every instance of item (ii)?

Comment: @Burak  I'm no longer bugged by any issues.  My confusion arose from my misunderstanding of how a formula was being used in Jech's proof.  While $\#\varphi_x(x)$ is not technically a formula in the language of set theory, it is **representable** by such a formula (when $\#$ is recursive, etc...).

Answer (score 4):

Tarski's theorem, as given in Undecidable theories, page 46, allows arbitrary numbering and is completely syntactic. I think this abstract version given by Tarski himself is the most clear. Let me summarize it here with some inessential variations.

Let $T$ be a consistent first-order theory (any consistent first-order theory). If $\varphi\mapsto \ulcorner\varphi\urcorner$ is a naming of formulas (**any** assignment of closed terms to formulas), then either the diagonalization function (the function $\varphi\mapsto \varphi(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$) is not representable (under that naming), or the set of theorems is not representable (under the given naming), or both are not representable.

In the case of ZF, assuming it to be consistent, we know that if we choose a recursive naming, we can represent the diagonalization function but not the set of theorems. Also, we can easily choose a (nonrecursive) naming which allows us to represent the set of theorems, but, then, the diagonalization will not be representable.

The proof is quite simple. If the diagonalization is representable, the fixed-point lemma can be proved quite simply. Assume that $V$ is a formula representing the set of theorems. Apply the fixed point lemma to get $\varphi$, a sentence satisfying 
$T\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow \neg V(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$.

If $T\vdash\varphi$, then, since $V$ represents the theorems, $T\vdash V(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$, and $T$ is inconsistent. If $T\nvdash \varphi$, then, since $V$ represents the theorems, $T\vdash\neg V(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$, and $T\vdash \varphi$ by the choice of $\varphi$. Therefore, $T\vdash \varphi$ and it is inconsistent by the previous argument.

**EDIT**

Motivated by the question in the comment, I will prove the fixed point lemma I have used above:

We are assuming that $T$ is a first-order theory and that the diagonalization is represented in $T$ under the arbitrary naming $\varphi\mapsto\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner$. It means that there is a formula $D(x,y)$ such that 
$T\vdash\forall y(D(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner, y)\leftrightarrow y=\ulcorner\phi(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\urcorner)$.

Now, let $W(y)$ be an arbitrary formula. Let $\phi(x)$ be the formula $\exists y(D(x,y)\wedge W(y))$ and let $\varphi$ be the sentence $\phi(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$, the diagonalization of $\phi$. This sentence is a fixed point for $W(y)$.

Indeed, $\varphi$ is $\exists y(D(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner,y)\wedge W(y))$, which, from the hypothesis on the representation of the diagonalization, is equivalent to $\exists y(y=\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner\wedge W(y))$. The last sentence is logically equivalent to $W(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$, and we are done.

Therefore, Tarski's result applies to arbitrary first-order theories and to arbitrary namings. The moral is that no matter what first-order theory and naming of formulas you choose, the representation of at least one of two simple metatheoretical notions 
(diagonalization and theoremhood) within the object theory will always fail.

Comment: I like this trichotomy.  Doesn't the fixed point lemma require more than just $T$ being a first-order theory?  Also, this  result is talking about validity rather than truth; am I right in saying that truth is representable iff validity is representable?

Comment: I have proved the fixed point lemma. Validity is more general than truth. Truth is validity when the theory is complete, that is, the theory of a model.

Comment: The Diagonalization Lemma (= the fixed point lemma) requires something like the Robinson Arithmetic Q. The diagonalization function must be (strongly) representable. 
In the language of set theory, the very weak "baby set theory" i.e.  "the adjunctive set theory" will do.

Answer (score 0):

In arithmetic, you can use numbers ("Gödel numbers") to code formulas, and numerals in the very language to name them. In set theory, you can similarly use finite sets, e.g. von Neumann ordinals, to code formulas, and simple set theoretical expressions to name them. 
This is done directly e.g. in Melvin Fitting: Incompleteness in the Land of Sets (Studies in Logic). 
But because we know that arithmetic can be interpreted in set theory, and in that sense arithmetic can be done inside set theory, we can also just assume that all the Gödelian techniques can be transported to set theory.